# Modifying static final constant field in a subclass

Tags: java, oop, private, protected

I am writing a concrete class that is intended to be subclassed sometime in the future. One of the fields is treated as a constant file path, but it is meant to be modified in subclasses. I currently have this declaration for PATH_TO_FILE.

```
public class MyFileHandler
{
    protected static final String PATH_TO_FILE = "/my/path/to/file"; 

    public void writeToFile(String s) { /* Write to PATH_TO_FILE */ }
    public String readFromFile() { /* Read from PATH_TO_FILE */ }
}
```

How can I allow subclasses to modify the variable PATH_TO_FILE? Should I use a different declaration?

Comment: `final` value cannot be overwritten.

Comment: It seems better to not refer to a hardcoded, static field for this. Use an instance variable, perhaps defaulting to `/my/path/to/file` if another value isn't supplied, and offer constructors that let subclasses set a different value.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it embodies a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
abstract class A {
   public abstract String getConst();
}

public class B extends A {
   @Override
   public String getConst() { return "path1"; }
}

public class C extends A {
   @Override
   public int getConst() { return "path2"; }
}
```